# Profile across a grids section non-default coordinate system Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am translating a Matlab piece of code to python with the help of libraries such as numpy and scipy. I have the following line in Matlab

```
[cE_U, cN_U, c_U] =improfile(X,Y,U,East,North,100);
```

where U is a 40x40 matrix indicating the velocity at the mesh marked by points (x1,y1), (x2,y2), ... indicated by vectors X and Y.
What i'm trying to achieve is get the velocity at points (East[0],North[0]), (East[1],North[1]),... which form a line across the mesh.
The problem is that East and North are not vectors containing indexes , they are vectors containing real world coordinates same as X and Y.
Also East and North define points that lie inside values from X and Y but are not the same, velocity at points (East[0],North[0]), (East[1],North[1]),... in matrix U,  must be interpolated. 
So far i have not been able to find a solution that defines a non-default spatial coordinate system as Matlab's improfile function does (https://la.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html).

I have tried scipy map_coordinates function(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html) but haven't been able to combine the two coordinate systems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you perform a 2D interpolation after creating a meshgrid from X and Y?

Comment: Yes, this approach actually worked. I used scipy griddata function because the velocity fields had nan values. Thanks for the idea